# Unresolved Dependencies?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I tried building my app and I fail with a single message:

`Failed to resolve: play-services-basement`

My app was building successfully yesterday. No code has changed since building successfully yesterday. Nothing in any of my `build.gradle` files have changed. This is crazy.

Does anyone have any pointers on what I can look at next to get my app building successfully?

EDIT: Some solutions online involve switching the orders of `google()` and `jcenter()` in my list of repositories such that `google()` comes first and `jcenter()` comes last -- but this doesn't solve my issue and the build still fails with the same message.

EDIT #2: Tried invalidating my caches and restarting. Build fail persisted. I tried assembling with debug and received a more specific message:

`Could not find play-services-basement.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/15.0.1/play-services-basement-15.0.1.aar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem this morning XD

update your libraries gsm google to

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidate cache and restart.

If that doesn't work, then you can assemble with debug or stacktrace to see where it is attempting to resolve your references.

[image]

Comment: Followed your steps and was met with an issue of which my first edit is offered as a solution -- but it doesn't solve the issue :(

Comment: What versions are you using? Did you migrate to androidx aka api 28?